# How to send long value from one activity to another?

Tags: android, listview, cursor, bundle

I am using ListView in my activity.
on any list item seleted(ID) it should display the entire row(associated with ID), in another activity.
I used bundle object to pass the long value using "putExtra". but that did not work either. may I know how could I get it done.?

**1st activity :**

```
Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
dataBundle.putLong("ID",id);

Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.mink7.databaseapplication", "com.mink7.databaseapplication.OnItemClickFromLV");
myIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

**2nd activity :**

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); 

if(extras !=null)
{
    long idd = extras.getLong("ID",0);
    Cursor c=db.getName(idd);
    final String name_ret = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("name"));
    final int age_ret = Integer.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("age")));
    final String city_ret = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("city"));
    t1.setText(name_ret);
    t2.setText(age_ret);
    t3.setText(city_ret);
}
```

Comment: try to use `long idd = extras.getLong("ID");` instead of `long idd = extras.getLong("ID",0);`

Comment: but even that doesnt work, I am getting this error. "no package identifie when getting value for resource number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the long directly, like `intent.putExtra("ID",value)` the extras are already a key value pair. Then the code for receiving the values on your second activity should be working.

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

For Pass Data from First Activity to Second Activity:-

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.mink7.databaseapplication", "com.mink7.databaseapplication.OnItemClickFromLV");
myIntent.putExtras("ID", id);
startActivity(myIntent);
```

For Get Data:-

```
Bundle bdl=getIntent().getExtras();
long id=bdl.getLong("ID");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
//First Activity(Pass Long Value through intent.putExtra("KEY",LongValue) )        
long longValue = 991909000000L;    
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Second.class);    
myIntent.putExtra("KEYVALUE",longValue);    
startActivity(myIntent);    
//SecondActivity (Second.class)(Get Long value through Bungle)    
Bundle b1 = getIntent().getExtras();
long longValue = b1.getLong("KEYVALUE");    
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Long Value :- " + longValue,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();        
//Manifest.xml (define your second class file in manifest file)    
<activity android:name=".Second" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can directly pass the value to activity without using bundle.

```
myIntent.putExtras("ID",id);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// In Activity A                 
Hashtable hashtable = new Hashtable();  
/* adding element in hashtable */  

Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);    
intent.putExtra("hashtable", hashtable);  
intent.putExtra("MyClass", obj);  
startActivity(intent);   

//in Activity B  
Bundle bundel = getIntent().getExtras();  
try{  
    ads = (myClass) bundel.get("MyClass");  
    hashtable = (Hashtable) bundel.get("hashtable");  
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.i(" Error at bundle " , e.toString());
}
```

and use this link u can pass all value from one activity to another activity..

http://www.coderanch.com/t/470615/Android/Mobile/Passing-object-one-other-activity

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
myIntent.putExtra("ID",id);
```

check this for more info

http://droidweb.com/2010/02/developer-tip-10-passing-data-between-activities-via-bundles/

Answer (score 0):

hey guys i was able to get it done.

use

t1.setText(String.valueOf(name_ret));

instead of

t1.setText(name_ret)